# jQuery datatable without bootstrap

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [jQuery datatable](https://datatables.net) and it is working perfectly fine with basic UI (look and feel).I want to use bootstrap for other UI elements under same page but adding bootstrap css and js links ,datatable grid UI converts into bootstrap theme.I want to keep datatable UI as it ( no bootstrap/default ) and would like to use bootstrap for other UI in same page.What is the way to remove bootstrap theme from datatable only.

Comment: I don't think that there is easy way but It's seems that bootstrap effect so much on the widget. See http://live.datatables.net/duforegu/1

Comment: Thanks ,Is there any bootstrap theme available which I can be apply on datatable. Any pointers will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rename each class used by the other element to make sure the look and field is not alterate.

The easy way is to import the datatable as is.

Add new element and rename each class it use.

Provide us small example of your code to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Download builder](https://datatables.net/download/index), in the **Styling** section select **DataTables**. Don't use Bootstrap classes for tables and they will have default look as designed by DataTables author.